# What is Galaxy S3 (m0)

Tags: android, crash-reports, samsung-mobile

I recently developed an application targeting Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4. I ve noticed that the only crashes I have is from Samsung Galaxy S3(m0. Does anybody know what exactly is this (m0).
Is it a specific model or what?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can query some information about devices with fields in android.os.Build, eg.

- Samsung Galaxy S4:

  ```
  Build.MODEL returns String "GT-I9505"
  Build.DEVICE returns String "jflte"
  ```
- Samsung Galaxy S3

  ```
  Build.MODEL returns String "GT-I9300"
  Build.DEVICE returns String "m0"
  ```

**UPDATE (14 Oct 2014) :**

- Samsung Galaxy S5

  ```
  Build.MODEL returns String "SM-G900F"
  Build.DEVICE returns String "klte"
  ```

so `m0` is the String returned by Build.DEVICE fro SGS3.

Answer (score 1):

M0 refers to the ARM Cortex-M processor:
http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-m0.php

Comment: What makes you say this?